# How to pull the numeric value from a byte in an array with C

Tags: c, int, hex, type-conversion

I have an array of hex values, if I want to pull the numeric value from a particular hex values how would I do that? say the hex value is 08? I wanted to convert this to an int? Thank you!

my array is declared as :
uint8_t *array = NULL;
and filled using fread()

I get the following warning `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` on these lines:

```
int a;
int i;
for(i =0; i < array_size; i++){
    a = (int)array[i]
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about an array of Strings which hold hex values in them?

Comment: sorry i declared the array for uinnt8_t, would I even need to convert or would it do it automatically?

Comment: Think you may have hex values stored as character arrays (strings) and not int values. Please have a look at my answer about using `strtol` and see if that helps.

Comment: @ChrisduPreez `passing argument 1 of ‘strtol’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
    a = (int)strtol(array[i],NULL, 16);`

Comment: If i am understanding correctly `array` was used as the buffer parameter in your `fread()` meaning each element in `array` would be an representation of an ascii character read from file. Is your intention is to separately 'use' each character read from the file?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an array of hex values stored as `string` you can simply use `strtol` to convert them for example:

```
int decimal = (int)strtol("bbccddf0", NULL, 16);
```

If your hex values are not stored as `string`, a cast to `int` should achieve what you are looking for. For example:

```
int int_variable = (int) hex_variable;
```

Comment: the array is declared as uint8_t * array. Would these be strings? I used fread()

Comment: So would it automatically convert it to an int? Sorry I am new to C.

Comment: i suspect so, yeah. Maybe use a cast to int for example: int variable = (int) hex_variable;

Comment: Can you look at my edit to the question and help me sort through it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show more of your code - especially where you are trying to cast.

Comment: Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

in C, an hex value is preceded by 0x. for instance 0xF equals 15, and 0xFF equals 255.
for assigning a hex variable to an integer variable, the operator ' = ' will do the job. for instance, a[4] = b[4], whare a is integer, and b is hexadecimal.

I have an example of a code for easier understanding of hexadecimal numbers assignments in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int x = 0xF;
    /* it also works as declaring unsigned x = 0xF */

    printf("x in hex = %x\n", x);
    int a = x; /* you can declare an variable value and assign to it the hex variable */

    printf("a = %d\n", a); /* the output is : 15 */
    printf("x = %d", x); /* the output is : 15 */
}
```